# Mocha + Mongoose + Q hanging

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, q

I'm creating some data for a test in a mocha `before` hook.

It looks like this:

```
before(function(done) {
    var createUser1 = function() {
        return Q(User.create({<userdata>})).then(function(user) {
            user1 = user;
        });
    };

    var createUser2 = function() {
        return Q(User.create({<userdata>})).then(function(user) {
            user2 = user;
        });
    };

    createUser1()
        .then(createUser2)
        .then(done)
        .catch(done);
});
```

For some reason, this hook times out (i've upped the timeout to 12s just to ensure it didn't need more time).  Any idea why that'd be?

Edit: I also tried returning the promise via: `return createUser1().then(createUser2);` but that also timed out

Comment: a bit more debugging shows that the handler for the first `create` isn't getting called.

Comment: I think this is a bug with mongoose's error handling...changing `<userdata>` to an empty object (`{}`) works fine.

Comment: see https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/2570

Comment: How about using ```User.create``` in a callback way instead of promise way? IE ```User.create({data}, cb)```?